# Gridlayout draws child views on top of each other

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am trying to add a Dynamic Gridlayout to a parent Linearlayout which has a textview.

Here is the code.

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity {

LinearLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams;
GridLayout.LayoutParams mGridLayoutParams;
Button[] button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_main);

    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.ll);

    mLayoutParams =new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(this);
    gl.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
    gl.setOrientation(GridLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    gl.setColumnCount(8);
    gl.setRowCount(1);
    button = new Button[8];
    mGridLayoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    mGridLayoutParams.height=android.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        button[i] = new Button(this);
        button[i].setLayoutParams(mGridLayoutParams);
        button[i].setText(String.valueOf(i));

        gl.addView(button[i]);
    }
    parent.addView(gl);
}
```

}

And this is the layout am using

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/ll"
tools:context=".ActivityMain" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="New Product Form"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:typeface="serif" 
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

since I have a reputation less then 10 i cannot upload the image from my device.
please find the output which i am getting at this link
[DEVICE IMAGE](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=16k6dlt&s=5)

can anyone please explain what is wrong that i am doing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I realized that the problem occurs at the line when I am trying to set the layout parameters of Button widget "button[i].setLayoutParams(mGridLayoutParams);" . Can anyone explain why this is happening.

Comment: have you found out a solution? I am not having better luck with my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568525/view-fills-all-the-available-space

Comment: I dint get the chance to work on it further I think it should work out if you can find better ways to declare LayoutParams.

Answer (score 1):

Espionage. Every button should get a new GridLayout.LayoutParams. Wish this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31836423/898431

Comment: This is the solution!