# View fills all the available space

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am trying to use `GridLayout` programmatically.

Here is my code:

```
    GridLayout p = new GridLayout(this);
    p.setRowCount(20);
    p.setColumnCount(20);
    View c = new View(this);
    c.setBackgroundColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkbluetheme));
    Spec specusata = android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.spec(1,2);
    Spec specusata2 = android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.spec(1,2);
    p.addView(c,new LayoutParams(specusata,specusata2));
    setContentView(p);
```

Here is the result I get:

[image]

**While i was expecting something like this:**

[image]

**Please what am I doing wrong???**

Thanks !!!

EDIT EDIT EDIT

This happens even if i set the LayoutParams of the View to WRAP_CONTENT:

```
    GridLayout p = new GridLayout(this);
    p.setRowCount(20);
    p.setColumnCount(20);
    View c = new View(DayActivity.this);
    c.setBackgroundColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkbluetheme));
    Spec specusata = android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.spec(1);
    Spec specusata2 = android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.spec(1);
    c.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    p.addView(c,new android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams(specusata,specusata2));
    setContentView(p);
```

Comment: @Hardy Hi Hardy, I am not sure I understand. I think I set the the ncessary LayoutParams when I do `p.addView(c,new LayoutParams(specusata,specusata2))`... please could you explain me a bit better? Thanks! LISA

Comment: this means that the View is appear in full screen.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta thanks Piyush, could you please make an example, I still don't get it...maybe I am stupid...     :-( Thanks! LISA

Comment: @LisaAnne Ya.. i will be sure help you..why not??

Comment: Hey Lisa.. Did you check this example ? http://sampleprogramz.com/android/gridlayout.php

Comment: are you using android.support.v7.????

Comment: @Piyush Gupta yes I am using support.v7

Comment: @Hardy Thanks for the example Hardy. No problems if I use TextViews. The problem happens if I use View !!!

Comment: try to get LayoutParams of GridLayout for view......

Comment: @LisaAnne Any specific reason for using GridLayout dynamically ?

Comment: @Hardy unfortunately yes :-(((((   I need to build a daily calendar page with events, and I want to put blue cells for representing the event, there might be several events in a day, of different duration (n ow rows) and some events might overlap. I need to do it dynamically because every day is different!

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18034/android-a-to-z

Comment: @LisaAnne.... I think the problem is being created because of not getting layoutparams for view object......

Comment: Yes.. I seen..So nothing happen there??

Comment: @Hardy thanks Hardy but I cannot get to the chat because in office I am behind a firewall  Sorry :-(

Comment: @PiyushGupta same result as before...

Comment: LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT change it with LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT for only width....

Comment: @LisaAnne LOL ok i understand. But you should go with other ways also. Without use of GridLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO: Your other rows and columns are empty, and thus zero width. The rest of your space is filled with that single cell, and takes all space.

Try adding more child views with other colors, and then you will understand what happens.

Comment: thanks Hugo. it is funny...i have added another View in Red `b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
  specusata = android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.spec(5);
  specusata2 = android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.spec(5);
  b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  p.addView(b, new android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams(
    specusata, specusata2));`                    AND NOW I GET A FULL SCREEN RED!!! :-(

Comment: A view without a forced size of sized content will behave strangely when used with WRAP_CONTENT, as there is NO CONTENT. Force a minimum size, of put some subview with content in it. Remember: a layout is only about alignment, not about size. Your assumption that a grid layout will get you a evenly sized row or column is wrong. It only forces that the item in row 2, column 1, will have the same left position as the item in column 1, row 5.